# Will a 77-82mm stepup + filter fit with stock hood on Sony 70-200mm 2F.8 GM?

Tags: filters, sony, lens-hood

I am about to buy a Sony A7RIII + 16-35mm F2.8 GM + 70-200mm F2.8 GM and want to use the same  X4 CPL filter. I plan on buying the 82mm X4 CPL (which will fit the 16-35mm) and using a stepup to allow me to use on the 70-200mm. My only question is: will this fit on the 70-200mm with the stock lens hood?

Answer (score 1):

No. It will not. Once you use a step-up ring, the hood cannot mount.

Comment: Ah shame. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to make the answer as accepted for others to know.

Answer (score 0):

A CPL filter is not very useful on a wide-angle lens, you will get too much brightness differences in the sky. Better to buy your CPL for the tele-zoom lens only.

Comment: Great tip, thanks!